# Issue with Docker Swarm, Likely Related to Networking

Tags: networking, docker, docker-swarm

I'm facing difficulties while trying to use Docker Swarm on a VM. The same process worked perfectly on my local machine.

I initialized Docker Swarm on the VM with the command:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr MY_IP_HERE
```

Then:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-swarm.yml app_name
```

For example, docker-swarm.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - global

networks:
  global:
    driver: overlay
```

In the terminal:

```
docker service ls
```

Output:

```
ID                  NAME        MODE        REPLICAS  IMAGE          PORTS
5ns3ui99o82a        app_nginx   replicated  1/1       nginx:latest   *:80->80/tcp
```

In the terminal:

```
curl http://localhost or my_ip
```

Output:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

I believe it is related to the network portion, but I don't know what to do, as if I weren't exposing port 80:80. However, on my computer, it exposes normally. This only happens on the VM.